# is it possible to open revision history window of TortoiseHg from the vim?

Tags: vim, tortoisehg

I need to edit hg files in vim. For now, when I need to see the history of the file, I need to locate this file, right click on this file and then select TortoiseHg->Revision History menu to get the history.

I have tried to find out the registry table of this menu. It's `TortoiseHgCMenu` and the value is `{46605027-5B8C-4DCE-BFE0-051B7972D64C}`. I don't know what does it means. I originally thought it should be like `xxx.exe --special-paramter-to-open-the-revision-history-window`.

So, is there any commands to open the revision history window? so that I can use it inside the vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a `thg.exe` tool that allows to launch TortoiseHg tools from the command-line. With that, you can define a custom Vim command, e.g.

```
:command! HgLog call system('thg.exe log ' . shellescape(expand('%:p')))
```

<sup>Note: Untested; I don't have TortoiseHg installed; the tool will tell you which arguments it needs.</sup>

#### Alternative

If you'd rather stay in Vim for viewing the log (though the representation surely isn't as nice as in a dedicated GUI tool like TortoiseHg), I can recommend the excellent [vcscommand.vim - CVS/SVN/SVK/git/hg/bzr integration plugin](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=90).